# Java: Why am I getting "';' expected" for an if statment

Tags: java, if-statement, bluej

the if in the constructor is supposed to check if the input is legal... the compiler does not seem to agree with me, it gives me "';' expected" after the if statment, and I dont get why please help.

```
public class RGBColor
{
    private int _red,_green,_blue;
    private final int _MAX_INTENSITY = 255,_MIN_INTENSITY = 0;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class RGBColor
     */
    public RGBColor()
    {
        _red = 0;
        _green = 0;
        _blue = 0;
    }

    public RGBColor(int red, int green,int blue)
    {

        If ((_red < _MIN_INTENSITY) || (_red > _MAX_INTENSITY) || (_green < _MIN_INTENSITY) || (_green > _MAX_INTENSITY) || (_blue < _MIN_INTENSITY) || (_blue > _MAX_INTENSITY)) \\<<I get the error here
        {
            _red=0;
            _green=0;
            _blue=0;
        }
        else
        {
            _red = red;
            _green = green;
            _blue = blue;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: `If` vs `if`. ``\\`` vs `//`.

Comment: my guess would be, that `if` should be lowercase.

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly post... thank you for the fast response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "If" has a capital "I" so the compiler thinks you're declaring a type.

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly post... thank you for the fast response